# Blurry CSS transitions when using filter

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm working on a site that uses CSS to create hexagons. This technique uses a transform to rotate a box, clip the edges uses `overflow:hidden` and then rotates the image inside the opposite direction to appear straight and display the hexagon, [here's the codepen](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd) I modified to get it working. As you can see the transitions work just fine.

The problem I'm running into is now is that I want to apply a greyscale filter on hover to my design and I'm finding that all my transitions are now blurry. In Firefox Dev Edition I'm seeing the image and text start sharp, go blurry on hover, then go back to sharp. When looking in Chrome everything is blurry, hover or not.

[image: Sharp greyscale vs blurry transition]

```css
.hexContainer {width:400px;}
#categories {overflow:hidden;width:100%;margin:0 auto; padding:0 0 1em; position: relative;}
#categories .hexBox {position:relative;list-style-type:none;width:100%;padding-bottom:115%;float:left;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform:rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);transform:rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg); z-index: 10;}
#categories .hexBox *{position:absolute;visibility:visible;}
#categories .hexBox>div{width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;color:#fff;overflow:hidden;-webkit-transform:skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);-ms-transform:skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);transform:skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
#categories .hexBox img{left:-100%;right:-100%;width:auto;height:100%;margin:0 auto;  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%); transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }
#categories .hexBox h3 {position: absolute; bottom: 25%; left: 2%; font-weight: 300; color: #fff; transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;}
#categories .hexBox h3 strong {font-weight: 700; padding-left:.25em;}
#categories div p{width:90%;padding:0 5%;}
#categories .hexBox p{padding-top:50%;top:110%;padding-bottom:50%;}

/* hovers */
#categories .hexBox div:hover p{top:50%;padding-top:10%;}
#categories .hexBox div:hover img { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); filter: grayscale(0%); -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }
#categories .hexBox div:hover h3 {bottom:40%;}
```

You can see the issue here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwgebO

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I frequently run into this issue as well. I assume this is a browser-level optimization to render transformations in lower detail while a given element is undergoing a transition (so that it doesn't have to redraw the element in full detail per each frame). The workarounds I use involve fast transitions and an easing curve that is not too soft on the borders (near 0 and 1 on `x` axis).

Comment: @JánosWeisz Could you elaborate on that a little more? I'm not sure what you mean by "easing curve that is not too soft on the borders". I tried shortening up the transition speed, which it 1/4 second is already pretty fast and didn't see any improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I have a solution. It isn't blurred in my system, at least.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbLKpV)

What I have done:

1) Important: the image was being displayed rescaled. Native resolution 500x500, but assigned width 480px. That isn't helping to make display crisp

2) Changed way of getting grayscale. removed filter from the image, and added blend mode

```
#categories .hexBox img{
    left:-100%;  
    right:-100%; 
    margin:0 auto;  
    mix-blend-mode: luminosity;  
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

Now, for the blend mode to give results, we need white background in the container

```
#categories .hexBox>div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: white; 
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

And we set the transition on it.

Now, for the fadeout of the grayscale filter, all we need is to make the container transparent

```
#categories .hexBox div:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Support for blend modes is more or less equivalent to filters.

Comment: Just made the changes to my design and it works perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, looks like it fixed the problem in Firefox, but Chrome for Mac and Windows is still blurry. Can you look on your system and see if you're seeing the same in Chrome?

Comment: It isn't blurry in my system .. But I don't have standard Chrome settings. will investigate a little bit ...

Comment: I can't see it blurry. May be try removing the translatez ?

Comment: It was the translatez, that was something I picked up in my code from another SO thread trying to fix blurriness in Chrome for retina, so it wasn't necessary.